# A property in an ember component is not propagating to its parent controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a component `priority-selector` that looks like this...

```js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    priority: 'low',
    didInsertElement: function() {
         this.$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    },
    actions: {
        click: function(priority) {
            this.set('priority', priority);
            this.$('.btn-primary').removeClass('btn-primary');
            this.$('.btn-for-' + priority).addClass('btn-primary');
        }
    }
});
```

Template code...

```js
<div class="pull-right btn-group" role="group">
    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-for-low" {{action 'click' 'low'}}>LOW</div>

    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-for-medium" {{action 'click' 'medium'}}>MEDIUM</div>

    <div type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-for-high" {{action 'click' 'high'}}>HIGH</div>
</div>
```

I use this component in a template like so...

```js
<div class='col-sm-3'>
    {{priority-selector priority=priority_gender}}
</div>
```

And I have it specified in the controller...

```js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    ...
    priority_gender: 'low'
    ...
})
```

But the property in the controller never changes when I interact with the component, I can observe this to be the case by looking in the ember inspector.

Comment: Did click handler working (check by setting a breakpoint there)? Could you change priority_gender property value to something not equal to default value for the component? What do you see then?

Comment: I added a breakpoint, and it hit reached that code so that click handler is working. And when I change the default value in the component, it still uses the one set in the controller.

Comment: And what argument does the click handler receive in your test?

Comment: The argument is the priority, so either "low", "medium" or "high", depending on what the user clicks

Comment: Okey. Could you provide the component's template code, please? And there is another check you could make before digging `Ember.set` method: change `priority_gender` value in the controller in Ember Inspector and check if it affects on component's `priority` property.

Comment: I tried editing the priority in the inspector, but no joy. The question has been updated with the template code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92210/discussion-between-microfed-and-saralk).

Comment: Let `priority` to be an `Ember.Object` like `{'val':'low'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your code is working.](http://ember-twiddle.com/ce2ae91a9fcac1c92ef7)

So, make sure to specify `priority_gender` in right controller for template you're using `priority-selector` component.